# LOAD DATA INFILE and spatial data

Tags: mysql, spatial

On MySQL 5.7, I used to populate the "point" column of a table with `LOAD DATA INFILE` and a `SET` clause, i.e.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'myfile.txt'
REPLACE INTO TABLE mytable
(@x, @y)
SET geom = Point(@x, @y);
```

This worked just fine.
I upgraded to MySQL 8.0.12, and I now get an error `ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'geom' doesn't have a default value`.

Has something changed in the way `LOAD DATA INFILE` handles `SET` clauses ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has been [confirmed](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91893) in 8.0.12.
The only workaround I found was :

1. Drop the geom column
2. Load data into the (x, y) columns
3. Recreate the geom column without a not null constraint
4. Update the geom column
5. Alter the column to add the not null constraint

Answer (score 0):

Simply method is to create table without spatial (point/geo) fields and load data as text, next load data from this (temporary) table to target table like below:

1. load data to temporary table with simply types of columns
2. insert to target table from temporary table converting needed columns to spatial.